# How can I classify exceptions purely?

Tags: haskell, exception, types

So my code *(by design)* gives me an exception, and I need to find out if it belongs to a specific
*"class"* of exceptions — in any sense of the word. I can do it like this:

```
data Case a = ExpectedException | SuddenException | AsynchronousException | Result a

classifyExceptionM :: forall m. MonadCatch m => m () -> m (Case ())
classifyExceptionM a = fmap Result a `catches`
    [ Handler ((\e -> return ExpectedException)     :: ArithException     -> m (Case ()))
    , Handler ((\e -> return SuddenException)       :: ArrayException     -> m (Case ()))
    , Handler ((\e -> return AsynchronousException) :: SomeAsyncException -> m (Case ()))
    ]
```

This is ugly but it works. Now I wish to perform the same classification in pure code. Yet again,
I may throw my exception with the [pure `Catch` monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/exceptions-0.10.2/docs/Control-Monad-Catch-Pure.html#t:Catch) and catch it again:

```
classifyException' :: Exception e => e -> Case ()
classifyException' e = either undefined id $ runCatch $ throwM e `catches`
    [ Handler ((\e -> return ExpectedException)     :: ArithException     -> Catch (Case ()))
    , Handler ((\e -> return SuddenException)       :: ArrayException     -> Catch (Case ()))
    , Handler ((\e -> return AsynchronousException) :: SomeAsyncException -> Catch (Case ()))
    ]
```

Pure, works, but ugly all the same.

What I wish to have is something like this:

```
classifyException :: Exception e => e -> Case ()
classifyException e = case sortOf e of
    DivideByZero     -> ExpectedException
    IndexOutOfBounds -> SuddenException
    StackOverflow    -> AsynchronousException
    _                -> error "Encountered unclassifiable exception"
```

— But I could not pattern match on exceptions because of their tragically abstract nature.  The
closest I can get is this:

```
classifyException :: SomeException -> Case ()
classifyException (SomeException e) =
    if typeOf e == typeOf DivideByZero then ExpectedException else
       if typeOf e == typeOf (IndexOutOfBounds "") then SuddenException else
          if typeOf e == typeOf (SomeAsyncException StackOverflow) then AsynchronousException else
             error $ "Encountered unclassifiable exception: " ++ show e
```

Notice how I need to specifically select `SomeException` as the type of my exception. This is
because all exceptions are secretly wrapped in this type when they are thrown, and `typeOf` any
exception I could catch is always `SomeException`.

It is all just a sorrowful mess. How can I improve?

Comment: What is the purpose of this?  What do you hope to achieve by adding complexity to an already complex system?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am actually trying to simplify. I am writing a test suite for an abstract factory of abstract factories, and I need to make sure it reacts to exceptions in a prescribed fashion. So I give it a sequence of locally exceptional data and retrieve a sequence of `Case`s. Then I compare the two sequences — the invariant is that they match.

Comment: What don't you folks like about this post? Is it unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think perhaps your question is more about style than substance, which is why it's not received much attention - the end point is somewhat unclear. Some of your attempts could be tidied, eg.

```
classifyException' :: Exception e => e -> Case ()
classifyException' e = fromRight (error "blah") $ runCatch $ throwM e `catches`
    [ Handler @ArithException     $ const $ pure ExpectedException
    , Handler @ArrayException     $ const $ pure SuddenException 
    , Handler @SomeAsyncException $ const $ pure AsynchronousException
    ]
```

Two other alternatives,

```
classifyException :: SomeException e => e -> Case ()
classifyException = \case
    (fromException -> Just ArithException) -> ExpectedException
    (fromException -> Just ArrayException) -> SuddenException
    (fromException -> Just AsyncException) -> AsynchronousException
    _                                      -> error "Encountered unclassifiable exception"
```

or (with some language extension soup)

```
classifyException e =
  if | is @ArithException -> ExpectedException
     | is @ArrayException -> SuddenException
     | is @AsyncException -> AsynchronousException
     | otherwise          -> error "Encountered unclassifiable exception"
  where is :: forall e. Exception e => Bool
        is = isJust $ fromException @e e
```